# Points in the circle - performance

Tags: python, performance, loops, math

I'm learning python by solving CodeWars Katas. The exercise is: "Write a function that calculates the number of points in the circle". My code:

```
from math import sqrt
import time
start = time.time()

def points(n):
    count=0
    for i in range (-n,n+1):
        for j in range(-n,n+1):
          if abs(i)+abs(j)<=n:
            count=count+1
            continue
          if (sqrt(i**2+j**2))<=n:
             count=count+1
    return count

print (points(1000))
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

It's look like execution time for this is too long (7 second for points(1000), 21 seconds for points(2000)). How to make this more efficient (get rid of loops?).

Comment: This is more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Drop the innermost for loop, and instead use a binary search (or interpolation search) to find the edges of the circle on that row, and then count the points between them.

Comment: For each integer `y`, you can calculate directly the corresponding value of `x` for a point on the circle. This gives you the number of points on this line. And a circle is very symmetrical, use that as well!

Comment: Concentrate on speeding up the code within the inner-most loop where it matters the most. You don't need those two `if`s, eliminate the first one. The `sqrt()` in the second could be eliminated by comparing `(i**2 + j**2) <= n*n` although `n*n` should be calculated once and stored in a local variable at the beginning of the function since its value never changes.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't resist giving it a shot. So here is a method that splits the circle into a central square and four equal "caps":

```
[[0 0   0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0   0 0]
 [0 0   0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0   0 0]

 [0 0   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1   0 0]
 [0 1   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1   1 0]
 [0 1   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1   1 0]
 [0 1   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1   1 0]
 [1 1   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1   1 1]
 [0 1   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1   1 0]
 [0 1   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1   1 0]
 [0 1   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1   1 0]
 [0 0   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1   0 0]

 [0 0   0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0   0 0]
 [0 0   0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0   0 0]]
```

As suggested in the comments we do not check individual points; instead we find the outermost point(s) in each row of the top cap.

To that end we first cheaply compute all squares between 0 and N^2 by summing odd numbers.

Then we iterate through the squares 0, 1, 4, 9, ... (corrersponding to x coordinates) while detecting all the points where N^2 - y^2 is crossed. The y^2's are taken from the precomputed squares right to left until x and y meet.

Finally, we sum four caps and the central square.

Code:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def pic(N):
    squares = 0, *accumulate(range(1, 2*N+1, 2))
    N2 = squares[-1]
    i, j = 0, N
    cap = 0
    while 2 * squares[j] > N2:
        max_x2 = N2 - squares[j]
        while squares[i] <= max_x2:
            i += 1
        cap += 2*i - 1
        j -= 1
    return 4*cap + (2*j+1)*(2*j+1)
```

A numpy version of essentially the same algorithm:

```
import numpy as np

def pic_np(N):
    odd = np.arange(-1, 2*N+1, 2)
    odd[0] = 0
    squares = odd.cumsum()
    N2 = squares[-1]
    cut = squares.searchsorted((N2 + 1) // 2)
    cap = 2 * squares[:cut].searchsorted(N2 - squares[cut:], 'right').sum() - (N-cut+1)
    return 4*cap + (2*cut-1)*(2*cut-1)
```

And a brute force method for comparison:

```
def brute_force(N, show=True):
   sq = np.arange(-N, N+1)**2
   mask = sum(np.ix_(sq, sq)) <= N*N
   if show and (N <= 10):
       print(mask.view(np.uint8))
   return np.count_nonzero(mask)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def points(n):
    return n * n * PI
```

Or isn't that 'precise' enough. Are we looking at round points, square pixels - inside the line (and on what pixels is that line exactly?), ..? (maybe use `n-1` ?).

Answer (score 0):

its self explanatory

```
public static int pointsNumber(int radius) {
    int quater_updown = radius;
    //xxxxx
    for (int i = 1; i <= radius; i++) {
        quater_updown += sqrt(radius * radius - i * i);
    }
    //xxxx.
    //xxx..
    //xx...
    //x....
    //4 side and a center
    return 1 + (quater_updown) * 4;
}
```